# Qt Service does not enter the event loop issue

Tags: c++, qt, service

I used the old QtService code from: https://github.com/qtproject/qt-solutions/tree/master/qtservice and created a service to run `npm start` command which will start my website on Windows startup. When adding `-exec` argument, starting in app mode it works well but when it runs as a service it does nothing. During a debugging I found out that it does not entering the service event loop correctly. So, I created a small example which should write some text to a txt file to illustrate this issue.

**Code:**

*insuranceservice.h*

```
#ifndef INSURANCESERVICE_H
#define INSURANCESERVICE_H

#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QObject>
#include <QThread>
#include <QDebug>
#include "qtservice.h"
#include "servicelogger.h"

class InsuranceService : public QtService<QCoreApplication>
{
    Q_GADGET
public:
    InsuranceService(int argc, char *argv[]);
    ~InsuranceService();

private:
    void start();
    void stop();
    void pause();
    void resume();
    void processCommand(int code);
    void createApplication(int &argc, char *argv[]);
};

#endif // INSURANCESERVICE_H
```

*insuranceservice.cpp*

```
#include "insuranceservice.h"

InsuranceService::InsuranceService(int argc, char *argv[]) : QtService<QCoreApplication>(argc, argv, "InsuranceService")
{
    std::cout << serviceName().toStdString().c_str() << std::endl;
    setServiceDescription("Test service");
    setServiceFlags(QtServiceBase::CanBeSuspended);
    //setStartupType(QtServiceController::AutoStartup);
}

void InsuranceService::start()
{
    try {
        QCoreApplication *insuranceApp = application();
        QFile *logFile = new QFile(ServiceLogger::getLogPath(), insuranceApp); 
        logFile->open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Append);
        ServiceLogger::writeLog(logFile, QString("Test...").toUtf8());
        logFile->close();
        logFile->deleteLater();
    } catch (...) {
        qCritical() << "Failed to start the service!!!";
    }
}

void InsuranceService::stop()
{

}

void InsuranceService::pause()
{

}

void InsuranceService::resume()
{

}

void InsuranceService::processCommand(int code)
{
    Q_UNUSED(code);
}

void InsuranceService::createApplication(int &argc, char *argv[])
{
    QtService::createApplication(argc, argv);
}

InsuranceService::~InsuranceService()
{

}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include "insuranceservice.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    InsuranceService service(argc, argv);
    return service.exec();
}
```

Any ideas how to enter the service event loop correctly?

**Updated:**

I tried to run this service with the built-in `logMessage` method:

```
void InsuranceService::start()
{
    logMessage("The start method executing....", QtServiceBase::Success, 0, 0);
    QFile *logFile = new QFile(ServiceLogger::getLogPath());
    logFile->open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Append);
    ServiceLogger::writeLog(logFile, QString("Test...").toUtf8());
    logFile->close();
    logFile->deleteLater();
}
```

In the `Event Viewer` it reports: *The start method executing....*

But for some reason everything below `logMessage()` does not execute. The log file does not exists which should be created. It could be the issue that `logMessage()` runs on one instance and `QFile` creates/runs on another instance. I need somehow to connect to the right instance.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. I have properly debug the app and found out that `QProcess`, `QStandardPaths::writableLocation` and `qgetenv` are not working when app is a service. It seems that service functionality is limited. So, I decided to set my app to run at OS startup instead of a service. Now, it works well. The issue is resolved. Thanks.